# Align icon and bullet in itemize

Tags: itemize

I have a bullet list and each item starts with a shape.

```
\noindent Colors:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \crule[green]{0.8cm}{0.45cm} 
  \item \crule[green]{0.8cm}{0.45cm}
  \item \crule[green]{0.8cm}{0.45cm}
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Is it possible to align the shape with the icon?

Comment: Simply use `{\color{green}\rule[-0.225cm]{0.8cm}{0.45cm}}`.

Comment: please always post a small complete document. `\crule` isn't a standard command (and actually I have no idea which package defines it, although no doubt google would find it)